# Evenly partition contiguous sequences of numbers

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, partitioning

A frequent task in parallelizing `N` embarrassingly parallel work chunks contiuguously among `K` workers is to use the following algorithm to partition, in psuedocode:

```
acc = 0
for _ in range(K):
    end = acc + ceil(N/K)
    emit acc:end
    acc = end
```

This will emit `K` contiguous paritions generally of size `N/K` and works fine for large `N`. However if `K` is approximately `N` this may cause imbalance because the last worker will get very few items. If we define imbalance as the maximum absolute difference between partition sizes, then an iterative algorithm that starts from any random partition and reduces potential until the maximum difference is 1 (or 0 if `K` divides `N`) is going to be optimal.

It seems to me that the following may be a more efficient way of getting at the same answer, by performing online "re-planning". Does this algorithm have a name and optimality proof?

```
acc = 0
workers = K
while workers > 0:
    rem = N - acc
    end = acc + ceil(rem/workers)
    emit acc:end
    acc = end
    workers -= 1
```

**Edit**. Given that we can define the loop above recursively, I can see that an inductive optimality proof might work. In any case, the name and confirmation of its optimality would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of dividing the range is:

```
for i in range(K):
  emit (i*N // K):((i+1)*N // K)
```

This has the advantage of being itself parallelizable since the iterations do not need to be performed in order.

It is easy to prove that every partition has either `floor(N/K)` or `ceil(N/K)` elements, and it is evident that every element will be in exactly one partition. Since floor and ceiling differ by at most 1, the algorithm must be optimal.

The algorithm you suggest is also optimal (and the results are similar). I don't know its name, though.

Another way of dividing the ranges which can be done in parallel is to use the range `start(N, K, i):start(N, K, i+1)` where `start(N, K, i)` is `(N//K)*i + min(i, N%K)`. (Note that `N//K` and `N%K` only need to be computed once.) This algorithm is also optimal, but distributes the imbalance so that the first partitions are the larger ones. That may or may not be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler approach. You have `floor(N/K)` tasks which can be perfectly partitioned among the workers, leaving `N mod K` remaining tasks. To keep the regions contiguous, you can put the remaining tasks on the first `N mod K` workers.

Here it is in imperative style. Just to be clear, I'm numbering the tasks {0..(N-1)}, and emitting sets of contiguous task numbers.

```
offset = 0
for 0 <= i < K:
  end = offset + floor(N/K)
  if i < N mod K:
    end = end + 1
  emit {c | offset <= c < end}
  offset = end
```

And in a more declarative style:

```
chunk = floor(N/K)
rem = N mod K

// i == worker number
function offset(i) =
  i * chunk + (i if i < rem else rem)

for 0 <= i < K:
  emit {c | offset(i) <= c < offset(i+1)}
```

The proof of optimality is pretty trivial at this point. Worker `i` has `offset(i+1) - offset(i)` tasks assigned to it. Depending on `i`, this is either `floor(N/K)` or `floor(N/K) + 1` tasks.